# Открытие авторизации перед основной формой

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Перед входом в основную часть программы (Form1), нужно сделать авторизацию в Form2 (логин, пароль установлены перманентно в Form2). Как до открытия основной программы открыть дочернюю?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Мигание форм программы при закрытии в Delphi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/758281/%d0%9c%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-delphi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никаких проблем. Убираем Form2 из списка автосоздаваемых. В обработчике события OnCreate Form1 пишем:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Form2:=TForm2.Create(Self);
   Form2.ShowModal;
end;
```

Дальше возможны варианты по уничтожению Form2.

Comment: Работает, благодарю, но что обозначает (Self) и ShowModal?

Comment: В таком исполнении даже при закрытии формы (без авторизации) будет отображаться Form1. Нужно это учесть.

Comment: Не подскажите ли как?

Comment: @NickGrom Это как раз просто: в случае, если пользователь не прошёл авторизацию выполняете Application.Terminate непосредственно из метода Form2;

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, для не прошедшего у меня стоит ShowMessage('Wrong password'); Текущая проблема в следующем: при нажатии на крестик авторизации все равно открывается главная  программа

Comment: Благодарю все сделал. В событии OnClose (Form2) прописал Application.Terminate;

Comment: @NickGrom При этом если пользователь прошёл авторизацию, Terminate не должно вызываться :)

Comment: @NickGrom  Self - ссылка на экземпляр класса в пространстве методов которого вы сейчас находитесь, если проще - ссылка на Form1 в данном случае. ShowModal - вызов окна или формы без возможности переключиться на вызывающего.

Comment: Т.е. вначале мы создаем главную форму, потом вызываем окно авторизации, а потом выясняется, что главная форма зря создана и ее нужно удалить. Более того, для завершения программы предлагается использовать метод `Application.Terminate` который все, что делает - это устанавливает флаг `Application/Terminated = True`. Этот флаг проверяется аж в  `Application.Run`. Т.е. пока дойдет до проверки, мы еще успеем создать пару десятков форм из списка автосоздания

Comment: никто не мешает ввести свой флаг и не создавать форм, если не требуется, ДО проверки пользователя. А вы рискуете потерять код в DPR-файле в ряде случаев.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Покажите как Вы по флагу не будете создавать главную форму (которая до авторизации вообще не нужна). За 15 лет не потерял код ни разу. Наверное, я что-то делаю не так

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Хм... GOTO вы тоже используете, несмотря на рекомендации не использовать?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov а где я говорил, что не буду создавать главную форму, если код завязан на событии из неё? Вначале  у вас речь идет о "паре десятке форм", теперь "о главной форме". Сочиняете потихоньку? При текущем быстродействии, по большому счёту, не важно, какое количество кода успеет выполниться, если всё это всё равно незаметно для пользователя. А, поскольку я уже успел убедиться, что не стоит вносить лишний код в DPR, я продолжу это утверждать. "За 15 лет не потерял код ни разу" - рад за вас. За 21 год использования Delphi попался так 6 раз.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Вначале перечитайте, что Вам пишут, а потом говорите про сочинительство

Answer (score 1):

Убери форму авторизации из списка автосоздаваемых форм (либо через меню Project -> Options -> Forms, либо в файле проекта `.dpr` убираешь создание формы авторизации после `Application.Initialize;`).

Затем в файле проекта, до инициализации программы ( после инициализации программы `Application.Initialize;`, но до создания главной формы `Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);`), реализуй логику авторизации: создавай форму авторизации, покажи, реализуй логику проверки введенных данных и по результату проверки либо продолжение запуска программы, либо выход.

Например так:

```
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Form2 :=TForm2.Create(Application);
  if Form2.ShowModal = mrOK then
  begin
    Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
    Application.Run;
  end;
end.
```

Вообще логику авторизации можно вынести прямо в модуль формы авторизации в отдельную функцию, например `function Logon(): boolean`, внутри которой создавать форму, проверять введенные данные, и в конце уничтожать форму. И в файле проекта вместо `if Form2.ShowModal = mrOK then` вызывать функцию `if Logon() then`

Comment: Embarcadero не рекомендует без излишней нужды писать код в файле проекта. Проще использовать обработчик OnCreate для Form1.

Comment: @Alexey Kozlov, хотелось бы почитать про эту рекомендацию, чем же она обусловлена.

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov Ждем ссылку на источник.

Comment: Код в файле проекта (DPR) частично авто-генерируется (список uses, порядок создания форм, $R, к примеру). Чтобы не было проблем после редактирования свойств проекта, затрагивающих эти области, за изменениями в файле надо аккуратно следить, например, смотреть diff перед комитом.

Comment: @androschuk Пожалуйста: "Delphi project files are usually short, since most of a program's logic resides in its unit files. A Delphi project file typically contains only enough code to launch the application's main window, and start the event processing loop. Project files are generated and maintained automatically by the IDE, and it is seldom necessary to edit them manually." URL: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/2010/en/Programs_and_Units  Но, вообще, эта фраза горит жирным в book'е, который прилагается бонусом при покупке Enterprise версии

Comment: @Alexey Kozlov, не увидел для себя, что это именно рекомендация, что не надо писать код в файл проекта. Здесь приводится констатация факта, что **обычно** не пишется большая логика и что код в файле проекта создается автоматически и **редко** возникает необходимость править этот код. Так вот, я поэтому и писал, что лучше вынести логику авторизации в модуль и в файле проекта вызывать только функцию. И считаю, что редактировать файл проекта иногда все-таки не только можно, но и нужно. Никто и не призывал, что нужно всю логику реализовывать в файле проекта и превращать его в "помойку"

Comment: @VasilBaymurzin На самом деле, действительно, в файл проекта писать что-то моветон: 1. Модули (Units) должны быть максимально самостоятельны. В этом один из основополагающих плюсов системы, которую разработала Borland. В идеале, вы можете вырвать модуль из одного проекта и добавить в другой без каких-то изменений. Если же у вас при этом будут привязки к файлу проекта, это не есть гуд. 2. Не знаю, как насчёт любого team support'а, но оба, что есть у нас, нещадно коцают DPR-файлы, так что подобный подход при работе в команде не одобряется.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, согласен, но чем же помешает определение функции Logon в Unit2 с формой авторизации Form2 и его использование в dpr, самостоятельному использованию Unit2 с формой авторизации Form2? Таким же образом я могу утверждать, что использование в OnCreate главной формы создание и вызов формы авторизации связывает два этих модуля, причем в таком случае главная форма прямо зависит от формы авторизации и использоваться без нее не может. Что будет когда главная форма поменяется со временем, опять "не забыть" прописать форму авторизации в OnCreate ?

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, да, я согласен, что необходима осторожность в этом деле, и нельзя в файле проекта писать основную(сложную) логику программы, однако, в данном случае, я так полагаю, форма авторизации не является основной функцией программы и нужна она только единожды при запуске программы, и поэтому можно его заложить и в файл проекта.

Comment: @VasilBaymurzin >Что будет когда главная форма поменяется со временем, опять "не забыть" прописать форму авторизации в OnCreate ? Это, как раз, не проблема: конструктор формы (речь о Form2) обязан обрабатывать ситуацию, иначе универсальность модуля теряется. После этого вызывайте её хоть откуда.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, не совсем верно поняли мой вопрос. Вы же предлагаете вызывать форму авторизации (Form2) в `TForm1.OnCreate`, т.е. в момент создания главной формы. Таким образом главная форма оказывается жестко завязана на форму авторизации, то есть именно она не может существовать без формы авторизации. В случае, скажем, замены главной формы на TForm3, предлагаете опять же не забыть прописать вызов формы авторизации в `TForm3.OnCreate` и не забыть убрать из `TForm1.OnCreate`?

Comment: @VasilBaymurzin Ну, да. С точки зрения "не забыть" это ничем не отличается от "не забыть поменять вызов в файле проекта". Зато: 1. В случае изменения свойств проекта через IDE не приведет к затиранию этого вызова. 2. В случае работы в команде не приведёт к рассинхронизации/затиранию

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70256/discussion-between-vasil-baymurzin-and-viktor-tomilov).

Comment: @VasilBaymurzin 1) ни разу не видел, чтобы IDE затирала что-то в dpr файле. Максимум - это уехавшее форматирование. 2) Если ваша система контроля версий уничтожает dpr файл, то это весомый аргумент в пользу отказа от такой системы и переход на что-то более адекватное