# Мигание форм программы при закрытии в Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Имеется кусок кода. При закрытии окна авторизации (NPay) промигивает основная программа (Main) и программа завершается. Как устранить мигание?

```
Кусок кода из главного тела программы:
procedure TMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    NPay:=TNPay.Create(Self);
    NPay.ShowModal;
end;

procedure TMain.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
    Application.Terminate;
end;

Кусок из авторизации:
procedure TNPay.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
    Application.Terminate;
end;
```

Comment: суровый у вас способ закрытия приложений. зачем вам `terminate` в главной форме? вы форму авторизации при успехе просто скрываете что ли?

Comment: Хмм, а ведь и правда просто скрываю.

Comment: обычно там пишут а-ля `try r := f.showModal(); if(r = mrCancel) .... finally f.free();` в общем модальные окна имеют результат показа, используйте его.

Comment: Естественно будет мигать, вы показываете модально форму авторизации в момент создания основной формы, затем после закрытия формы авторизации создание главной формы продолжится и даже покажется, а затем произойдет "самоубийство" программы. Я так понимаю TMain - главная форма приложения, тогда не понимаю зачем в событии его закрытия убивать приложение?

Comment: Если пользователь не авторизовавшись - закроет NPay, то Main не должна открыться, как это реализовать более наглядным (новичковым?) способом?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В dpr файле пишем

```
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  if not TNPay.Login then
    Exit;
  Application.CreateForm(TMain, Main);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

В классе TNPay пишем

```
class function TNPay.Login: Boolean;
var
  LForm: TNPay;
begin
  LForm := TNPay.Create(nil);
  try
    Result  := (LForm.ShowModal = mrOk) and LForm.ValidateLogin;
  finally
    LForm.Free
  end;
end;

function TNPay.ValidateLogin: Boolean;
begin
  // Здесь проверяем корректность логина и возвращаем True/False
end;
```

Все `FormClose` убрать

**UPDATE**

Если есть желание долбить пользователя, пока он не введет нужного пароля, то делать так

```
class function TNPay.Login: Boolean;
var
  LForm: TNPay;
begin
  LForm := TNPay.Create(nil);
  try
    repeat
      Result := LForm.ShowModal = mrOk;
    until not Result or LForm.ValidateLogin;
  finally
    LForm.Free
  end;
end;
```

при желании в цикл можно добавить подсчет числа попыток

```
Cnt := 0;
repeat
  Result := LForm.ShowModal = mrOk;
  Inc(Cnt);
until not Result or (Cnt > 5) or LForm.ValidateLogin;
if Result and (Cnt > 5) then
  Result := LForm.ValidateLogin;
```

Comment: один раз ввел и все, на выход? :)

Comment: @teran Убедил :)

Comment: Изначально предлагал такой вариант автору [Открытие авторизации перед основной формой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/758085/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9), однако заминусовали, что не рекомендуется писать код в файл проекта, и что это моветон...

Comment: @VasilBaymurzin Почитал. Полный бред. Это единственно правильный вариант. А адептов `OnCreate` хочется убивать. Там я написал почему

Comment: Тогда как адепты написания полотенец в файле проектов, видимо, никогда не писали в команде с использованием Team Support, да и просто, видимо, не теряли код в DPR из-за того, что сделали какие-то изменения в IDE.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Я еще раз говорю, что лично у меня IDE ни разу не убивала dpr-файл. Форматирование - да сползало. Но код не терялся никогда. Может расскажете, как этого добиться? А по поводу сторонних программ - если сторонняя программа убивает ваш код, то кто же вам доктор?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Корпоративный стандарт - слышали про такое? Или только про доктора? У нас (и не только у нас, знаю не по наслышке) TeamSupport обязателен, раньше был RR. У меня IDE убивало. Поэтому и не советую